# Chrome overflow: scroll CSS issue (phantom margin/padding)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

So, I've got two divs that are holding individual tables (so that the top can act as a header and the bottom can act as a scrollable content area).

Everything is working fine functionally, but I've been banging my head against my desk trying to sort out this phantom border/margin that is showing up in Chrome on the scrollable area.

This is Firefox:

[image]

And this is Chrome:

[image]

As you can see, Chrome is rendering a faint margin/padding on the left of the scrollable area (starts where the "12a" time markers start. I've changed the background of the scrollable area to #ff0000 during testing to ensure that it is indeed not a border. But this is what it looks like without that style change:

[image]

I would add a simple margin-left to this element, but the calendar cells are rendered via javascript and cell width, etc are calculated based on the width of the container, number of days available to view and a couple other parameters. In tests, this proved to throw off the alignment of cells further right in the table.

Has anyone encountered this before? And is anyone aware of a way to disable this property on scrollable elements in Chrome? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

a border and scroll-bar is calculated in your total width. that seems to be why it looks as if the top box is pushed to the left, when it really is the couple pixels from the scroll-bar offsetting everything below it to the right.

try offsetting the scroll bar container with

```
left:-2px;
```

or however much the width is.

Comment: I've tried this approach, unfortunately my table cells are calculated based on the width of the table, so all this does is fix the problem in the cells furthest to the left, but as you scroll right, they still fall out of alignment. Thanks for the input, though.

Comment: Well with the limited info you gave that was the best I could see based on the images. 

Provide the html and css for better help